# How to detect if WooCommerce subscriptions checkout page is for a change payment gateway request?

Tags: php, woocommerce, payment-gateway, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I have a site using WooCommerce Subscriptions.  I do some processing in a `woocommerce_available_payment_gateways($available_gateways)` filter handler function and I need to detect if the checkout process was triggered by the user wanting to change their payment method for a subscription (woo user docs: https://woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/customers-view/#section-11).

After a lot of Googling all I could come up with was this:

```
WC_Subscriptions_Change_Payment_Gateway::$is_request_to_change_payment;
```

This is a public static property on [WC_Subscriptions_Change_Payment_Gateway](https://github.com/wp-premium/woocommerce-subscriptions/blob/master/includes/class-wc-subscriptions-change-payment-gateway.php), but it using it feels a bit nasty!

Does any one know of a cleaner way to do this?

-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL for change payment gateway request will be looking like `www.example.com/checkout/order-pay/1631818391/?pay_for_order=true&key=wc_order_3Qcv1jNShbWNt&change_payment_method=1631818391&_wpnonce=35a514c6ed`. So `isset()` of `$_GET['change_payment_method']` can be used in this context.